# How do you turn off version control in android studio?

Tags: android, version-control, android-studio

I set up my Github with android studio, everything worked fine, the problem now is though, that I can't seem to turn off, or get out of version control to use the IDE normally again.

This means that errors aren't shown, and it is really hard to debug because of this.

So how do I turn off version control (VCS) in Android Studio?

Comment: `This means that errors aren't shown`.  Huh?

Comment: As in if you spell a word wrong or variable name wrong, the error doesn't show when in VCS mode. It means you might not see it until running the application when it crashes.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

To disable VCS in Android Studio on a Mac do the following:

`Android Studio > Preferences...`

[image]

In the Preferences window, select `Version Control` and under `Directory` choose VCS dropdown to be `<none>`

[image]

Don't forget to click "Apply" in the general Preferences buttons at the bottom.

---

**For 2022...**

It would seem that Android Studio nowadays ***does not*** automatically ***start*** with version control turned on for a new project.

The default seems to be "off" at the beginning of a new project.

(It *does* conveniently make a ".gitignore" file for you but it does *not* default to trying to use version control.)

However, if later you do manually yourself start using git in the folder in question, Studio *does* turn on vcs inside Studio, i.e. exactly as seen in the image above. In that case you'll have turn it off inside Studio, exactly as shown above.

Comment: @JoeBlow I am currently using Android Studio for a production app. I have hit a couple of small bumps along the way in earlier versions, but haven't had any huge problems in a while. That being said, the project I am working with is not a gradle project. With gradle YMMV.

Comment: Thanks a ton , i was getting some errors with git and i'm just learning stuff and did;nt need Version control after all

Comment: Should you also delete the Git folder and the gitignore.txt from your Android project folder??

Comment: Works as well if I want to turn it on :)

Comment: It is proper and useful steps

Comment: But as long as the Android Studio is reopened, VCS/git starts automatically.

Answer (score 64):

In Android Studio **1.2.x**

**FILE -> SETTINGS -> VERSION CONTROL**

Here the root is shown, Press **(-)** button to delete.

Comment: Works for AS 2.2 as well.

Comment: Don't forget to click 'Apply'.

Answer (score 20):

The other answers weren't working for me, so I am adding my solution.

This message was driving me crazy:

[image]

I had trouble with the other suggestions, as my settings was not allowing me to save changes for version control none.

[image]

So I went into **Version Control / Ignored Files** and removed all ignored files for that project.

[image]

[image]

Then when I clicked back on **Version Control**

[image]

I found this [in this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29052942/3956566).

Answer (score 19):

VCS is a project specific setting which you can modify by going to `File -> Settings` then checking under the `Version Control` heading.

Alternatively, you could disable a specific VCS plugin under the `Plugins` heading.

Note: I have not used GitHub as VCS, but you should still be getting error display (syntax checking) in the IDE. VCS usage should not disable that, since that would make the use of an IDE completely pointless.

Comment: +1 for plugin drop. If you don't want to keep doing this per project, or deal with the "unregistered roots" issues, disabling the plugins (Git, GitHub, Subversion, Mercurial) is the only true way to go. I use version control from an external shell or GUI, and never want it in my IDE.

Comment: @delrocco Yeah, the "unregistered roots" issue drove me crazy and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

You can delete **vcs.xml** file and it will remove the VCS connected with your app. 'vcs.xml' file can be found in this location "*YourProject\ .idea\vcs.xml*"

Answer (score 5):

**Project > .idea > vcs.xml**

[image]

change vcs value to 'none'

Note : only current enabled project.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to settings from file menu
2. go to version control -> directory mapping
3. select vcs to none from dropdown menu

voila done
[image: Android Studio screen shot selecting "none" in Directory Manager]
[see larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3mf2.png)

Comment: `Directory Mapping` is where the ever-changing Android Studio is putting it now.