# Dark-blue file names in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Hello. I have imported an external library from web (KryoNet) into my Android Studio. Now I made a change inside this library's code (In UdpConnection file). Should I somehow resynchronize these changes or something? I don't know what this **exclamation-mark** and **dark-blue colour** mean. Aren't the changes saved?

Answer (score 6):

Open Settings and go to Editor > Colors & Fonts > File Status. This tells you what each color means.

Comment: Found it - it's an 'Edited File'. Still can't save it... Already checked that it's unsaved - added 2354245245 println's.

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio is the official IDE for Android app development, based on IntelliJ IDEA. Hence the blue color means the file has been modified or changed since the last synchronization with your version control repo. Refer [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/file-status-highlights.html?origin=old_help) for details.

If you want to modify the preference, you may refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029242/how-do-you-turn-off-version-control-in-android-studio).