# Android Studio: Disable gutter

Tags: android, android-studio, gutter

I have disabled everything there is to disable in the gutter, yet its this big:

[image: Disgusting gutter]

[image: Gutter not disabled yet?]

I don't want the gutter at all. It's ugly and not useful for me.

Halp!

Comment: that's were you put breakpoints, you don't use breakpoints?

Comment: No, almost never. If I have to I'd enable it again (happens once a month tops).

Comment: Did you ever find a way to disable it?

Comment: Sadly no. Apparently a minimalistic editor is not what anyone wants.

Comment: Crap gutter, takes up soo much space.. what a waste.. I hope they get a way to do this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029242/how-do-you-turn-off-version-control-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

Just in case for those who didn't know yet, you can set shortcut keys for `"Main Menu > View > Active Editor > Show Gutter Icons"` in 'keymap' in preference as you want. You can't disable it altogether, but at least can hide the area by each file. Currently I use Android Studio 3.5.3, but I believe you can do this in some earlier versions, too.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently as of now there is no way to disable that portion of the IDE.

Debugging is an essential part of software development and there are not many people that would like to disable that in an IDE. Of for that matter even thought about that - it's not taking that much space anyway. You could probably put in a feature request for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it in Android Studio Iguana and the gutter disappears either just for the active editor by doing [what Brian Hong says above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59430351/4235946), or everywhere by disablig it in *Settings* > *Editor* > *General* > *Gutter icons* and unchecking *Show gutter icons* at the top.